# Iterate over get_post_meta() result

Tags: get-posts

I have WordPress code like below.

```
function get_preselect_values()
{
    $volunteers = get_post_meta($_POST['element_id'], "volunteers", false);
    $users = array();
    
    foreach ($volunteers as $volunteer) {
        foreach ($volunteer as $volun) {
            $users = $volun['ID'];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($users);
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_preselect_values', 'get_preselect_values');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_preselect_values', 'get_preselect_values');
```

I am getting only the **First** value.

How can I get all values ?

Comment: You mean to get all the values of the `display_name` property?

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. Yes, `display_name` property.

Comment: The problem as I could see is with the `$users = $volun['ID'];` (you should use `$users[]` there). But, could you please undo your last edit and just append the full code at the bottom of your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clobbering the value in the `$users` array with every iteration of the `foreach` loop. To add a new item to an array, you should use `$users[] = {...}`, not `$users = {...}`.

```
function get_preselect_values()
{
    $volunteers = get_post_meta($_POST['element_id'], "volunteers", false);
    $users = array();
    
    foreach ($volunteers as $volunteer) {
        foreach ($volunteer as $volun) {
            $users[] = $volun['ID'];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($users);
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_preselect_values', 'get_preselect_values');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_preselect_values', 'get_preselect_values');
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what is `display_number`? I do not see any key with this name ?

A simple `foreach` like :

```
foreach ( $volunteers as $volunteer) {
    echo $volunteer['ID'];
}
```

Will display the Volunteer ID for example.

Comment: Thanks @Sébastien Serre. I tried with this but it is not working. I am getting error.

Comment: Could you paste the error you have and the code you wrote?